# What is the best way to break down a 60 minute gym workout?

Tags: nutrition, gym

I am just about to start a fitness/nutrition regimen but I am not sure exactly where to start. I will be able to do 5 days a week but thought it might be best to start with 3 days a week (Tuesday, Thursday, Saturday) for the first two or three weeks. I have a membership at Bally's. How can I get the most out of a 60 minute workout at the gym? I am programmer working what equates to two jobs and spend all of my time sitting. When not working, my time is occupied by two young kids and my wife. Being very busy has led to the sorry state my body/health is in.

I am going to be working out before work (at around 6am) and my time is limited, so I want to spend the time wisely. What machines should I use, how much weight should I start with, and what can I do to maximize my results in the most efficient way possible with the 60 minute restraint? As far as goals I want to be about 20 - 30 pound lighter but this is really just secondary - my priority is being healthy. I want to make sure I am around a long time, feeling good, and enjoying life.

Specifically what machines should I use, how much of the 60 minutes should be cardio, stretching, or lifting? Any advice or tips would be very helpful!

Comment: Wazzup, do you like the workout. It works you know. how old are you by the way?

Comment: 35, and thanks for the routine. I am going to gym tonight after work so I should have some info to report back. This was exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a starting strength program from Mark Rippetoe, it is a great program to build all your base strength. you will do 3 sets of 5 repetitions for each exercise except on the hyperextentions 3 sets and 8 repetitions. Here are the exercises.

**Tuesday**

- squat-start with 100 pounds
- bench press- start with 80 pounds
- dumbbell bentover row- start with 35 pounds
- hyperextentsion- body weight

**Thursday**

- squat-do 105 pounds
- overhead press- do 60 pounds
- chin up- body weight

**Saturday**

- squat-do 110 pounds
- benchpress- 85 pounds
- dumbbell bentover row- do 40 pounds
- hyperextentsion- 5 pounds

**Calorie Intake** 16 x your body weight= total calories a day. 50% should be protein 40% carbs and 10% fat. Stay away from wheat, potatoes, beer, sugar and fried foods. reduce calories to 2,500 when not exercising that week or only going once.

**Progressively Load** your exercises every workout adding 5 pounds to every exercise every workout. You can sorta see that in the monday and friday workout.

**Rest Between Sets**- 4-5 minutes between sets, rest this long or your hurting strength gains translating over to less calories burned.

**Aerobic exercises** you should get in 15 to 30 minutes of cardio 3 times a week. walking then working your way up to jogging. Its up to you when you want to work that in but not before you strength train do it on a different day or after you lift.

Comment: Can these exercises be done on the machines and if so do i need to increase the weight to compensate for the assist the machine provides. The only reason I ask is that the machines are "faster" so i save time not having to get the weight setup.

Comment: Yes they can but they dont work the muscles like free weights, free weights are always better. just work in as much free weights as possible and squats you have to use free weights.

Comment: I did the Tuesday workout minus the hyper extension forgot about it when i got to gym and to be honest i am not sure what it is. Today is the Thursday routine to be honest i am not sure i can do enough chin ups to make it worthwhile right now. Better suggestion instead of the chin up? After some of my own research this looks like a variant of the strong lift 5x5.

Comment: @Ominius You can checkout the original Starting Strength program [here](http://startingstrength.wikia.com/wiki/FAQ:Introduction), it's a good read. You could also consider getting that book if you are serious about lifting, it comes highly recommended. That website also specifically states that the workout it suggests will last around half an hour, with the time slowly moving up to about an hour (over the course of several months) which fit your time contraints fine.