# How can I transition from obese to Mesomorph?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, exercise, workout-routines

I am an obese person and have been working out for about two months now, I’ve been doing 30min cardio and 30 min lifting (usually upper body 3 x 10-12 , 110-130 lbs depending on area).

I know that I could do a better routine to build muscle , but my question is , Is there something wrong with building muscle and transitioning from obese to endomorph body type or should I go from obese to “fit” to endomorph?  If I can transition directly , what exercise do you recommend weightlifting wise?

I started at 410 lbs , this is my current body composition.

[image: Body composition]
[image: Body types]

Comment: Just as an aside, those classifications have been kind of debunked for years now.

Comment: @JohnP Good to know, but I’m using this as a reference of what I would like to work for.

Comment: I agree with JohnP that we should strive for different classifications, but I tend to accept the somatotypes for one thing: I know what people mean when they use them, so it helps speed the dialogue along.

Comment: Yes, I’m using it as a reference , it would take me longer to explain and I used the picture so people understand what  build I want to work for.

Comment: I wrote a somewhat lengthy answer to another question. If I were to write an answer here, I'd probably repeat a lot of it. Please give it a read. https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/37782/short-timeframe-health/37795#37795

Comment: This is not to say I won't write an answer here, but if a broad question can be made more specific, then all the better for you.

Comment: Ok, so I read the answer...Breakfast wise I’m eating 2 eggs and a banana, I can replace that with fasting until lunch , as lunch I’m eating 1/3 cup of any kind of carb ( usually rice)  or 1 cup of veggies and 1 cup or 8 oz of protein ( chicken ) . As for dinner usually at 6 pm I eat chicken and vegetables or salad ....But as exercise I’m a bit confused by the exercise the program I have ( I’m trying following the destroyer by Matt Vincent ) but in frustration I just make my own workout

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned in the other answer, don't try to make your own program. There are so many programs out there already, made by people who know what they're doing. There's no reason for a beginner to try and make their own.

Comment: Aren’t these all entirely dependent on your skeletal shoulder/hips ratio? Meaning that it’s not something that can be modified.

Answer (score 1):

Your first step is to go to a doctor, you might have hormonal issues that could stop your progress.
After done that I can advice you to focus better on lifting, try using high intensity routines that help you to burn more calories while lifting because it makes your body improve in many good ways (testosterone raise, metabolism boost) and find a good diet with frequent revisions.

This link can give you an idea about how your program should look like https://www.kagedmuscle.com/blogs/8-week-hardcore-trainer/overview-program#page_title

Even if you don't want to be a thin guy you still need to follow the same path

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Is that a common issue ? Regarding the diet I’m following my nutritionist specifications.